# React useState hook - set value

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to the whole React and React hooks staff, I'm trying to reset the value in useState to default if new filters are selected.

```
const [apartments, setApartments] = React.useState([])
const [page, setPage] = React.useState(1)
const fetchData = (onInit = true, loadMore = true) => {
        let setQuery = ''
        if (!loadMore) {
            setApartments([]) // <--- how to reset to empty?
            setPage(1) // <--- Not setting value to 1
        }
        if (!onInit || query()) {
            filtersWrapper.current.querySelectorAll('.select-wrapper select').forEach(item => {
                if (item.value) {
                    setQuery += `&${ item.name }=${ item.value }`
                }
            })
        }
        fetch(apiUrl + `?page=${ page }&pageSize=12${ setQuery }`)
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(data => {
                setApartments([...apartments, ...data.apartments] || [])
                setHasNextPage(data.hasNextPage)
                setPage(prev => prev + 1)
            })
    }
```

Comment: You are actually setting it properly, but the problem is that react will reset actual data in apartments and page variables in next frame, they would be empty array and 1. But the problem is that before next frame you are setting it again, in your fetch function, which overrides your setApartments([]) and setPage(1) and cousing unexpected behavior. To overcome this problem I think @CertainPerformance provided code for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Identify the page to pass to fetch from the `loadMore` argument, not from the state value. Similarly, identify from the argument what to pass to `setApartments`. This way, all the state gets updated at once, inside the fetch.

```
const fetchData = (onInit = true, loadMore = true) => {
    let setQuery = ''
    if (!onInit || query()) {
        filtersWrapper.current.querySelectorAll('.select-wrapper select').forEach(item => {
            if (item.value) {
                setQuery += `&${item.name}=${item.value}`
            }
        })
    }
    const pageToNavigateTo = loadMore ? page : 1;
    fetch(apiUrl + `?page=${pageToNavigateTo}&pageSize=12${setQuery}`)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => {
            const initialApartments = loadMore ? apartments : [];
            setApartments([...initialApartments, ...data.apartments]);
            setHasNextPage(data.hasNextPage);
            setPage(pageToNavigateTo + 1);
        })
        // .catch(handleErrors); // don't forget this
}
```

I'd also recommend changing the

```
filtersWrapper.current.querySelectorAll('.select-wrapper select').forEach
```

from DOM methods to setting React state instead.